# Magento2 transtion success_message

Tags: magento, magento2

how can I set translation for success message. it seems to be defined in 
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php 
You added %1 to your shopping cart.

I tried to add translation csv but it seems not working ...

thanks for help!
martin

Answer (score 0):

Solution is : custom theme had own translation code.